# When to use "$\;\to\;$" vs "$\;\implies\;$" in discrete math?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

I have started to look through discrete math textbooks to prepare for the next semester. However, I see two symbols used interchangeably:
"$\;\to\;$" and "$\;\implies\;$". I've learned that both imply. However, I want to know when I should use either.

Thanks!

Comment: A similar issue arises with the turnstile symbols $\vdash$ and $ \vDash$ where the single bar means syntactic consequence and the double bar semantic consequence.  My guess is that you are not working in an area where such distinctions matter. So you can use either, though $\implies$ may be better if it is less likely to confused with other meanings, as can happen with $\rightarrow$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a subtle difference.  $P\rightarrow Q$ is a statement, which could be either true or false.  $P\implies Q$ is the assertion that $P \rightarrow Q$ is true.  The single arrow is a (grammatical) conjunction.  The double arrow is a verb.

Comment: That is a nice explanation. But then why does one not make the distinction for other logical conjunctions (like $\land$, $\lor$) or for other verbs (like "equals", which  is written identically in equations (to solve) and in identities (that are interpreted to assert truths)).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I think it's because of the way we read the symbols to ourselves in our heads.  The rightarrow connective reads as a verb.  "And" doesn't.    But I have wished for a good long time that we distinguished between the various senses of "equals".

Answer (score 1):

Typically, one uses $\rightarrow$ to mean `imply' only in the context of writing out formal sentences in a propositional calculus, i.e. $\forall a\exists b .p(a)\rightarrow q(b)$. Outside of this, one typically uses $\implies.$

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know they both mean the same thing. Since it does not matter which one you use i would just pick one and stick to it. From what i have seen most people seem to use $\Rightarrow$.

Answer (score 0):

In some contexts the expression $a \implies b$ means that the [material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) $a \to b$ is a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)). This is only true for certain choices of expressions $a$ and $b$, and thus we would use $a \implies b$ only if $a \to b$ is (always) true.